# Is there a Python library equivalent of the Java's FixedThreadPool?

Tags: java, python, multithreading, threadpool

Is there a simple ThreadPool library in Python that has, for example, pool.execute(function, args) method, which should be blocked when the pool is full (until one of the threads becomes free)?

I have tried using ThreadPool from multiprocessing package, but its pool.apply_async() function doesn't block when the pool is full. Actually, I don't get its behavior at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [ActiveState Code Recipes page](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577187-python-thread-pool) has an implementation based on a [Python queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) to do the blocking. Use `add_task` where you would `execute`.

```
## {{{ http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577187/ (r9)
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

class Worker(Thread):
    """Thread executing tasks from a given tasks queue"""
    def __init__(self, tasks):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.tasks = tasks
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            func, args, kargs = self.tasks.get()
            try: func(*args, **kargs)
            except Exception, e: print e
            self.tasks.task_done()

class ThreadPool:
    """Pool of threads consuming tasks from a queue"""
    def __init__(self, num_threads):
        self.tasks = Queue(num_threads)
        for _ in range(num_threads): Worker(self.tasks)

    def add_task(self, func, *args, **kargs):
        """Add a task to the queue"""
        self.tasks.put((func, args, kargs))

    def wait_completion(self):
        """Wait for completion of all the tasks in the queue"""
        self.tasks.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from random import randrange
    delays = [randrange(1, 10) for i in range(100)]

    from time import sleep
    def wait_delay(d):
        print 'sleeping for (%d)sec' % d
        sleep(d)

    # 1) Init a Thread pool with the desired number of threads
    pool = ThreadPool(20)

    for i, d in enumerate(delays):
        # print the percentage of tasks placed in the queue
        print '%.2f%c' % ((float(i)/float(len(delays)))*100.0,'%')

        # 2) Add the task to the queue
        pool.add_task(wait_delay, d)

    # 3) Wait for completion
    pool.wait_completion()
## end of http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577187/ }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified @ckhan answer and added a callback feature.

```py
#Custom ThreadPool implementation from http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577187/
# Usage:
#       def worker_method(data):
#           ''' do processing '''
#           return data
#           
#       def on_complete_callback(data, isfailed):
#           print ('on complete %s' % data)
#           
#       pool = ThreadPool(5)
#       for data in range(1,10)
#           pool.add_task(worker_method, on_complete_callback, data)    
#       pool.wait_completion()

from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
import thread

class Worker(Thread):
    """Thread executing tasks from a given tasks queue"""
    def __init__(self, tasks, thread_id):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.tasks = tasks
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()
        self.thread_id = thread_id

    def run(self):
        while True:
            func, callback, args, kargs = self.tasks.get()
            try:
                data = func(*args, **kargs)
                callback(data, False)
            except Exception, e:                
                callback(e, True)
            self.tasks.task_done()

class ThreadPool:
    """Pool of threads consuming tasks from a queue"""
    def __init__(self, num_threads):
        self.tasks = Queue(num_threads)
        for i in range(num_threads): Worker(self.tasks, i)

    def add_task(self, func, callback, *args, **kargs):
        """Add a task to the queue"""
        self.tasks.put((func, callback, args, kargs))

    def wait_completion(self):
        """Wait for completion of all the tasks in the queue"""
        self.tasks.join()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
```

Comment: ThreadPool does not support blocking behaviour when pool is full... As Ognhej also mentioned in his question...